# Should we rename the 'untagged' tag?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

I'm doing some tag cleanup (mostly adding accent marks), and came across the [untagged](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag.

Should we rename this to Spanish? And if so, to what?

The obvious option would be [sin-etiqueta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-etiqueta), but then I thought better, since the rest of the UI is still in English and uses the word 'tag'. This made me think perhaps [sin-tag](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin-tag).

Thoughts?  Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend **deletion**. It seems that that tag is there just as a way to avoid using an actual tag.

Since tagging is a way of adding meaningful information to our questions and we have plenty of tags, I can't think of a reason why a question shouldn't be tagged or couldn't be tagged (if the latter is the is, a new tag can always be created or suggested, or the question even retagged).

All the questions that seem to use the "unttaged" tag could actually use another of the meaningful tags that we have. So, keeping the tag could only cause a detriment in the quality of the questions or the information search mechanism of the site.

**Edit**

After seeing Flimzy's comment, I thing we should rename the tag as **no-tag**. That will do in both languages and will also keep the tag for the uses Flimzy is describing.

Comment: This tag happens when a tag is removed from the system, leaving a message with no other tags, or when a post is migrated from another site. Tags are removed when they receive very little attention. Yes, we ought to remove that tag from all questions, and add meaningful tags, but that won't get rid of the 'untagged' tag--it's a feature of SE, and will always exist.

Comment: @Flimzy,  I already retagged some of those questions.After knowing this, I edited my answer.

Comment: `no-tag` it's an excelent idea @Diego